# Javascript toggle button fails the if condition

Tags: javascript

Guys what am I doing wrong? On my pc this code: [simple toggle](https://jsfiddle.net/zartu/qbvfu9bj/) shows me false === True when I call the function for the first time. Why it goes on else when status is false?

```
  var status = false; 

  function toggleStatus() {
  var message = "status:" + status;
  if (status === false) {
      message += "===FALSE";
      status=true;
  } else {
      message += "===TRUE";
      status=false;
  }
  alert(message);
  }
```

Comment: Mhhh, seems to be working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qbvfu9bj/2/

Comment: Yes, Im getting 'status:false===FALSE' the first click and 'status:true===TRUE' the second click. Maybe you still have an older version cached or your machine or something.

Comment: so now I get that too on fiddle ..but on my server still doesn't work with booleans ...if I change the flag to a string and compare against that it works..any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be because there's already a window.status defined (which is a string, and used for the text in the browser status bar).

Because you're not protecting the global namespace from your code, the status variable is being defined as a global on the window object. Presumably the browser is going to stomp all over that.

This however should work https://jsfiddle.net/72rf8g8p/:

```
(function(){

var status = false; 

  function toggleStatus() {
  var message = "status:" + status;
  if (status === false) {
      message += "===FALSE";
      status=true;
  } else {
      message += "===TRUE";
      status=false;
  }
  alert(message);
  }

toggleStatus();

})();
```

You can also simply change the name of your variable to something else, such as myStatus:

```
var myStatus= false; 

  function toggleStatus() {
  var message = "myStatus:" + myStatus;
  if (myStatus=== false) {
      message += "===FALSE";
      myStatus=true;
  } else {
      message += "===TRUE";
      myStatus=false;
  }
  alert(message);
  }
```

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks. Btw your first code didn't work, but second is fine.

Comment: Dang, any idea why? I'll remove it, I think second answer is simpler to understand anyway.

Comment: I don't know..I tried it and didn't work. And yes, second is better. But the explication from first part is also good.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'll keep the 1st part. It may not work for you, in that the toggleStatus function won't be defined globally, so you can't call it manually, which is why I call it right after calling.